# Java 8 Optional-class: return value if nullable

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I'm trying to convert an existing snippet of code to some fancy Java 8 one-liner.

```
private static final Map<Integer, Foo> FOO_MAP = ...

public static Foo getForCode(final Integer code) {

  if (code == null) {
    return null;
  }

  final Foo foo = FOO_MAP.get(code);
  if (foo== null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown foo for code: " + code);
  }

  return foo;
}
```

My solution so far, which is lacking the handling if the param is null.

```
public static Foo getForCode(final Integer code) {
  return Optional.ofNullable(code).map(FOO_MAP::get)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Unknown foo for code: " + code));
}
```

Comment: Hopefully the “solution” illustrates why Optional is not a general replacement for `if` statements.  Your original code is clearly superior.

Comment: Yep. I hoped that there was a real "one-line" replacement, which I was missing.

Comment: @VGR A single `Optional` instance is not designed to perform distinct checks as the OP wants but it doesn't mean that it should not be used as type of return of the method. `Optional` allows to convey that the return may contain nothing and it also prevents `NullPointerException`.

Comment: The behavior of returning `null` if the input is `null`, is questionable to begin with. The preferred behavior is “fail-fast” instead of letting the programmer trace backward through the program to find out, where the original `null` came from. When you replace `Optional.ofNullable(code)` with `Optional.of(code)` in your code, you already have the recommended behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very readable, but you can :

```
Foo result = Optional.ofNullable(code)
            .map(x -> Optional.ofNullable(FOO_MAP.get(x))
                              .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Unknown foo for code: " + code)))
            .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 4):

you can returning `Optional<Foo>` from `getForCode(final Integer code)` and let the client deal with the optional value returned.

```
public static Optional<Foo> getForCode(final Integer code) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(code).map(FOO_MAP::get);
}
```

Comment: Exactly: use the exception of `get` instead of the original one.

Answer (score 4):

Without changing the behavior of the original function, I don't think `Optional` buys you anything here, except the opportunity to bury some complex conditionals within its methods and lambdas. If you were to minimize the conditional expressions, using if-statements and boolean expressions, you'd end up with this:

```
Foo getForCode(Integer code) {
    Foo foo = null;
    if (code == null || (foo = FOO_MAP.get(code)) != null) {
        return foo;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown foo for code: " + code);
    }
}
```

This is a tad more readable than any solution using `Optional`, to my eye, though it's still pretty obscure.

If you're willing to change the semantics of the function, and to return an `Optional`, then the [suggestion from Roshane Perera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49113091/1441122) seems like a reasonable approach (+1).

Comment: That does what the OP’s original code does, but I consider “return `null` if the input is `null`” as discouraged as overusing `Optional` (or even worse).

Comment: @Holger I agree; I detest the "return-null-if-input-is-null" antipattern. I had actually started to write an editorial comment on that very topic, but then it started to turn into an essay, which seemed like it would be a distraction from the answer. :-) But there seems to be a legitimate use case, which is that some object might or might not have a code, but if it has a code, it must be have an entry present in the map. I wouldn't express those semantics using "return-null-if-input-is-null" though.

Comment: @Stuart Marks Splitting a part of the logic in the client code (suggestion from Roshane Perera) means in a some way creating an artificial split and a reading indirection for a logic that should be at the same place. Besides, if the method is invoked multiple times you will have to repeat the duplication in the client code or worse introduce an helper method to do that. I am really not sure that it be fine.

Comment: @davidxxx It's hard to say without knowing more specifics about the OP's actual use case. But I'll note that the OP's code can return `null`, so the logic for handling that is already spread among all the callers. Returning `Optional` instead of a nullable reference makes this logic less error-prone, but it doesn't fundamentally change the callers' responsibility.

Comment: @Stuart Marks I agree about the broadness of the expected logic. " it doesn't fundamentally change the callers' responsibility." Of course but this solution changes the actual caller responsibility in the OP code without functional reason but having the `getForCode()` method lighter to handle the `Optional`.  So, yes it is more elegant but maybe not the suitable way as handling a null from the client side is one thing but handling both that and the exception rising is another thing.

Comment: @davidxxx Exception? Oh, Roshane Perera's code doesn't throw any exceptions. The comment on that answer is in error. The caller only has to deal with a present or empty `Optional`, with no exception handling.

Comment: @Stuart Marks  Sure, I referred to `if (foo== null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown foo for code: " + code);
  }` that is deported to the client side.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle it alone first.
Trying mixing both cases in a single statement may make it less readable.

Note that actually you usage of `Optional` is probably not required.
`Optional` makes more sense for return type.  In your actual code you go on to return `null` value.

Here is a usage of `Optional` where you return an `Optional` to handle both cases a returned `Foo` and no returned `Foo`:

```
public static Optional<Foo> getForCode(final Integer code) {
    if (code == null)
        return Optional.empty();

    Optional<Foo> optional = Optional.ofNullable(map.get(code));
    if (!optional.isPresent()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown foo for code: " + code);
    }
    return optional;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was to fast with editing and realised now: You are mixing return types. You return an Optional in case code is null, but else you return a Foo.

Comment: @Malte Hartwig No problem. I had just adapted the code of the question without looking carefully it. Don't worry, I updated with a correct code.

Comment: What I mean is that `orElseThrow` returns `Foo`, but `empty` return `Optional`. You will have compiler errors one way or another when copying it into an IDE. You'd have to wrap the result of `orElseThrow` in an `Optional` again, for example, or check "manually" with `isPresent`.

Comment: @Malte Hartwig Thanks !  Not still used enough to Optional ! I will try with an IDE the last time :)